# Address of members of a struct via NULL pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, null

Why the following expression is not a (null pointer) runtime error?

```
typedef struct{
           int a,b,c;
          } st;

st obj={10,12,15};
st *ptr1=&obj;
st *ptr2=NULL;

printf("%d",*(int *)((char*)ptr1+(int)&ptr2->b));
```

Comment: The correct way to do this sort of thing is the `offsetof` macro in `<stddef.h>`.  (`offsetof` is often implemented in terms of null pointer arithmetic, but that's because it's part of the C library that goes with a specific compiler, so the writers know that the compiler will be okay with it.)

Comment: @aschepler That! Exactly.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are performing pointer arithmetic on a `NULL` pointer which invokes undefined behavior - and that's not required to crash.

Comment: That's nice, but the question is tagged [c], not [gcc-extensions].

Comment: @ouah Nobody does pointer arithmetic on `void *` in this example.

Comment: @aschepler but may be the asker doesn't know the difference GNU C and C that's why...if he knows the reason he wouldn't ask the question

Answer (score 2):

actually, in GNU C, `&ptr2->b` while `st *ptr2=NULL;` produce the data member 'b' 's byte offset in the struct, it is 4 here

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, dereferencing a null pointer doesn't always crash! Sometimes it just happily moves ahead, accessing invalid memory!

You're probably seeing the output value '12'. What the compiler is doing when you dereference a pointer is adding an offset to get the address of member.

`int`s are typically 4 bytes long, so if `ptr2` had an address of, say, 10, then `ptr2->a` must also be at address 10, `ptr2->b` must be at 14, and `ptr2->c` must be at address 18.

Since ptr2 is `NULL`, it's adding 4 to get to member `b`, and `NULL`+4=4. Then you're adding 4 to `ptr1` and dereferencing that, which gets you `ptr1`'s `b` member!

But this is *not* portable, and you shouldn't do this!

Comment: &ptr2->b is equivalent to &(ptr2->b) as precedence of operator -> is more than & operator. So ptr2 is NULL then evaluating ptr2->b should result in seg fault. If in the same problem & operator is not used the program crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is perfectly legal usage because the "take address of"-operator actually means: "Do not load/store the value of the variable, just give me the address you have computed to access it." It stops the access before the actual undefined behaviour is invoked.

This is such a typical idiom in programming that it was actually encapsulated in the offsetof() macro (which is used quite extensively in linux) and has since made its way into the compilers themselves to provide more meaningful error messages. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offsetof for more details, even though I disagree with this article on the legality of the statement.

Comment: Who and why downvoted it? Is it not correct answer? +1